# wordpress bloginfo filter name and description

Tags: wordpress, plugins, add-filter

I was trying to edit my wordpress site name and description, I got that I have to add a filter plugin like so: `add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'My_function_name', 10, 2 );`.

It works, but I can't understand why we have to add the `10, 2` parameters? and which values it belongs to?

Also there wasn't enough information in [codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

Here is my working plugin :

```
function edit_bloginfo($text,$show ){
    if (isset($_COOKIE['switch_language'])) {
        if($show == 'description'){
            $text = 'New description';
        }
        if($show == 'name'){
            $text = 'New site name';
        }
      return  $text;
    }

}
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'edit_bloginfo', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In `add_filter( 'filter_hook', 'your_function', 10, 2 );` expression, the `10, 2` parameters are:

1. the first: the priority of your filter function during the execution of all filter functions. it is a number between
   1 and ∞ ( use a reasonable one : )  ), many thanks to @brasofilo: look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78829/is-there-a-limit-to-hook-priority).
2. the latest:  the number of parameters that will be passed to your
   function. The number of parameters declared and the number of parameters passed has to be the same.

Take a look to WordPress Codex [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @iEmanuele Oh, I'm doing plugins long time ago and forgot about priority , maybe because I was focusing too much in the bloginfo itself, thank you very much.