# Wordpress search field in specific menu bar

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I added a search field to my menu bars by using this code;

```
function menu_search($items){
    $search = '<li class="menusearch">';
    $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
    $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
    $search .= '<input type="submit" class="menusubmit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />';
    $search .= '</form>';
    $search .= '</li>';

    return $items . $search;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search');
```

But this adds the bar to all my menus, since I'm using multiple menus this is a problem. How can I make it so that the search bar only shows up in my main navigation bar?

I tried using the tutorial found here;http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/ but the search bar won't show up in my menu bar at all anymore. Maybe I'm using the name or the theme location wrong, this is what shows up in my menu screen 'Default (The Main Menu)'.

This is the rest of my functions file if needed;

```
<?php
ob_start();
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { add_image_size( 'orbit-custom', 920, 300 ); }

/**
 * Add a search bar to the navigation menu.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

function menu_search($items){
    $search = '<li class="menusearch">';
    $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
    $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
    $search .= '<input type="submit" class="menusubmit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />';
    $search .= '</form>';
    $search .= '</li>';

    return $items . $search;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search');

// This adds more than one menu location
add_action( 'init', 'register_multiple_menus' );
function register_multiple_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'footer-nav-mid' =>  'Middle Footer Navigation',
            'footer-nav-left' =>  'Left Footer Navigation',
            'footer-nav-right' =>  'Right Footer Navigation'
        )
    );
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Downloads Button Homepage',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s buttons">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Locator Button Homepage',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s buttons">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Specials Button Homepage',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s buttons">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Store Locator',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Email Me',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Download Left',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Download Mid',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
   register_sidebar(array(
       'name'=>'Download Right',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
       'after_widget' => '</div>',
       'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
       'after_title' => '</h4>',
   ));
}

if ( 
    !isset( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'] ) 
    || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) 
) 


 ?>
```

Comment: @usernotfound has answered first. : )

Comment: @iEmanuele doesn't matter who answered first, but your solution isn't working at the moment, see my comment ;)

Comment: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/search-box-on-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `add_filter`, you must tell WordPress to provide the callback function with the $args variable. In short, try this:

```
function menu_search($items, $args){
    if( $args->theme_location == 'footer-nav-mid')  {
        $search = '<li class="menusearch">';
        $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
        $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
        $search .= '<input type="submit" class="menusubmit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />';
        $search .= '</form>';
        $search .= '</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search', 10, 2); // <-- the 10 is the default priority, the 2 is the number of variables to pass to the callback function.
```

Replace "*footer-nav-mid*" with the slug of your menu location. This is set when you register your menu using [`register_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu):

```
register_nav_menu('footer-nav-mid', 'Middle Footer Navigation');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah ah! Trust me, i have not copied your answer! : )

Comment: @iEmanuele I believe you! You still forgot to update the `add_filter` call to send 2 variables to the callback functions ;) Cheers!

Comment: I feel hopeless, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675643/wordpress-bloginfo-filter-name-and-description/18676035#18676035). : )

Comment: too much information in a short time ... I think it's just a good night's sleep and I come back as new.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message when I use it; 'Notice: Undefined variable: search in .....' it says the problem is with the 'return $items . $search;' line. Weird thing is this error shows up with all my other menus, all except for the one I named in the piece of code.

Comment: @Kelly if the solution works please consider accepting the answer ;) Otherwise please let us know what error do you get. Cheers!

Comment: You need to concatenate `$items` and `$search`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the 2nd parameter ( $args ) to wp_nav_menu_items filter, to check if theme_location value is the right one.

```
function menu_search($items, $args){
    if( $args->theme_location == 'YOUR THEME LOCATION VALUE' ){
    $search = '<li class="menusearch">';
    $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
    $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
    $search .= '<input type="submit" class="menusubmit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />';
    $search .= '</form>';
    $search .= '</li>';
}
    return $items . $search;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search', 10, 2);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your solution will not work without adjusting the `add_filter` call – see my answer.

Comment: @usernotfound, thank you. i guessed that the default parameters number  were 2 instead of 1. : )

Comment: @ iEmanuele you're welcome ;) The default is 1: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Answer (score 0):

This is a much simpler solution - add the following to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
        return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'>".get_search_form(false)."</li>";
    return $items;
}
```

In this function, you will see that the IF statement is checking for a desired location - specifically, this example is checking for the Primary Menu:

```
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
```

You could also use something like this to determine which menu:

```
$args->menu->slug == ‘the_menu_slug’
```

If there is a primary menu, it returns whatever you have in the "return $items" quotes:

```
return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'>".get_search_form(false)."</li>";
```

In this case, I created a list-item and concatenated the **get_search_form()** WP function.

Most importantly, for this to be displayed in your menu as a list-item, you need to set the get_search_form() to false:

```
get_search_form(false)
```

This is because of the follow argument in the get_search_form() function:

> $echo
>   (bool) (Optional) Default to echo and not return the form.
>   Default value: true

- [Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)

This will successfully achieve the desired search form in any particular menu.